# How can I improve my hand-to-hand combat?

Tags: risen-2

I am terrible at fighting in *Risen 2: Dark Waters* game. I have searched on Google for useful combat tips (especially against fellow humans, though I can use monster tips), but I have come up dry. What can I do to improve?